# asp.net - How to get / deserialize object of JsonPatchDocument?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json-patch

I could serialize the `JsonPatchDocument` model by using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`, but the type of result is string, how can I convert it to normal array type? Or how to get `JsonPatchDocument` object straight to array?

```
var pathSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patch);
Console.WriteLine(pathSerialized);

// Result as string: 
// "[{"value":"2018-08-30","path":"/openTo","op":"replace"},{"value":"2018-04-01","path":"/openFrom","op":"replace"}]"
```

Comment: uhm ... that is the purpose of `SerializeObject` ... it provides you with a string representation of whatever you feed it. If you want those json-objects in a separate array, you have to serialize them each on their own
or did i miss something?

Comment: I want to check condition of properties of that object, then string type is impossible to check it, that's why I wanted to get the object. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Why serializing it then in the first place? Why not just accessing the properties of `JsonPatchDocument`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused as well. You're starting with a full-fledged strongly-typed object, converting it to a JSON string, and then complaining that you don't want it to be a JSON string. Then, don't convert it to a JSON string.

Comment: @croxy I tried to access properties directly, but then it returned error like `JsonPatchDocument does not contain definition of 'path'`. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: Because it *doesn't*. Based on the serialized string, `patch` is actually a collection type, meaning you'd need to do something like `patch[0].path`, i.e. get an item from the collection *first* and then access the `path` property off that.

Comment: Yea, i'm noob, my classmate told me that I had to serialize it first, but this would not go to anywhere, then I just made question here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to serialize the `JsonPatchDocument` object at all. You can access its properties directly through the object. For example filtering for the path property:

```
var elementsWithPath = patch.Operations.Where(o => o.path.Equals("some path"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking to do something with [`JTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) from the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace. You can turn the `pathserialized` string into a `JToken` with `var jToken = JToken.Parse(pathSerializer)`, then explore the underlying objects and properties by enumerating them with var `childTokens = jToken.Children()`.

One of those child tokens is going to be a `JObject`, which is a Json representation of an object. You can access properties of a `JObject` with `jObject["propertyName"]`.